# Android Room relation in separate table

Tags: android, foreign-keys, retrofit, android-room

I have two objects: `User` and `UserType`. Both are loaded as a list from a REST service and stored in separate tables.

The `User` objects that are send by the REST service contain a *typeId*, which is the *id* of the `UserType`. The `UserType` object should be loaded when I load a `User` from my database. How do I do this?

Notes:

1. Using an `@Embedded` UserType in my User class would store the UserType in the User database. I would rather have separate tables
2. Using a `@Relation` is intended to return a List of UserTypes, so this does not fit the model.
3. Using a `@TypeConverter` as described here https://medium.com/@josephdalughut/saving-embedded-entities-to-separate-room-tables-using-typeconverters-635f9e189e89 is not possible: when I save a User, its UserType object would be reduced to an *id*. When I load this user, the *id* would be replaced with the UserType. The problem here is that the REST service only sends a *typeId*, which means that for every User in the received list, before saving it, I would need to fetch the UserType and set it on the user, just to allow the TypeConverter to convert this UserType back to its id..

User:

```
@Entity(tableName = "users",
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(
        entity = UserType.class, 
        parentColumns = "id", 
        childColumns = "typeId", 
        onDelete = ForeignKey.SET_NULL, 
        onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE),
        indices = @Index("typeId"))
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("Id")
    protected long id = -1;

    @SerializedName("Password")
    private String password;

    @SerializedName("FirstName")
    private String firstName;

    @SerializedName("LastName")
    private String lastName;

    @SerializedName("GsmNumber")
    private String gsmNumber;

    @SerializedName("BirthDay")
    private Date birthDay;

    @SerializedName("TypeId")
    private long typeId;

    // ???
    private UserType userType;

    public User() {

    }

    // getters and setters
}

@Dao
public interface UserDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void save(User u);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void save(List<User> us);

    @Delete
    void delete(User u);

    @Delete()
    void delete(List<User> us);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id")
    User load(long id);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM users")
    LiveData<List<User>> getAll();
}
```

UserType:

```
@Entity(tableName = "usertypes")
public class UserType {

    private int color;

    public UserType() {

    }

    // getters setters
}

@Dao
public interface UserTypeDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void save(UserType t);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void save(List<UserType> ts);

    @Delete
    void delete(UserType t);

    @Delete()
    void delete(List<UserType> ts);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM usertypes WHERE id = :id")
    UserType load(long id);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM usertypes")
    LiveData<List<UserType>> getAll();
}
```